# Does IP Address also gets passed in the Http Header with RestTemplate call by default or not?

Tags: java, http-headers, resttemplate

I am making a HTTP url call using `RestTemplate` with the below simple code. Here url is one of our `Service` which will be extracting IP Address from the header.

```
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
```

So my question is does the `IP Address` also gets passed in the HTTP Header while making the url call or not in the way I am doing as shown above?

My service is running on `machineB` so if I am hitting that url from `machineA` using the above `RestTemplate` code does `machineA` IP Address gets passed in the header or not?

Or Do we need to do any extra stuff to pass the `IP Address` in the header while making the url call?

Comment: try to use an proxy, sniffer application such us jmeter, or wireshark, or a linux command such us tcpdump or ngrep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address of the client is not automatically passed in an HTTP standard header, as the HTTP server would have no need for this information. The IP address of the client is already available to the server via the IP packets used to transport the HTTP request.

If you want to have the client send it's IP address in an HTTP header you will have to create a custom header and fill it in with each request.